# Azure Devops multiple artifacts based on different configs or one artifact

Tags: angular, azure-devops, continuous-integration

currently I'm bussy creating an CI/CD for my angular frontend project. I have a specific git strategy but and have a CI/CD question regarding that:

We have a master/dev branch branches. What I want is the following:

- When I commit code to the dev branch, I want the CI to create an
  artifact and deploy it to a test environment.
- When I commit code to the master branch, I want the CI to create
  an artifact and deploy that to the production environment.

Do I need to build two different artifacts or just one? Because for the production and test environment I have different project configurations. For example: I want my project to connect with the production database if it's deployed in the production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to build one artifact and apply different configurations when deploying to multiple environments.

In Angular, you can use a config.json file to store environment related information. You can create one file for each environment and store them as [secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps. Before deploying, [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) and copy the related file into your artifact.

You can also store each configuration keys/values as [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) and replace it in your config.json file using [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you very much, is this 100% going to solve my problem? Do you have any experience with this? Because I have been searching for a long time, but read a lot, but didn't find any good solution.

Comment: I'm using a pipeline which deploy a web application and use DevOps secure files for storing environment related configuration. It is working quite well yes. Here is a [tutorial](https://dev.to/thisdotmedia/continuously-deploying-angular-to-azure-app-service-with-azure-devops-4hf2) which explain the other method (using variables) for an angular application.

Comment: Which approach do you recommend? I would like the implementation not to be complex.. hope you can answer this last question!: )

Comment: For me the easiest way is to use one file per environment and wrap it into the artefact before deploying